# What's the easiest way to paste my current address or zip-code into a web field in my browser?

Tags: browser, gps

Many web services have you dump your zip code (e.g. radio station locators) or address (for bus directions) into some fields on a form to give you information.  Obtaining this data seems tedious (go to Google maps...current location...remember the address...type it back in) or otherwise impossible (get current zip-code while on the highway).

Is there some easy way to copy an address or zip code string to paste it later?

Comment: I'd like to see an app for that: get zip code for current GPS location.  Would be sweet.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Clipper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rojekti.clipper). From Google Maps, share your current location & choose Clipper from the menu. Or, if you've [Copy to Clipboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.johanhil.clipboard) or [AndMade Share Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andmadesoft.share.pro) installed, you can just `Copy to Clipboard` (Clipper monitors clipboard). Or, if you've location in mind, you can enter it in Clipper manually.

Whenever you need to paste an address or zip code, just pull down notification to launch Clipper. From Clipper, tap desired item to copy it to clipboard. Now, don't ask how to paste. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If it is your known home address or you have just a few you use, you could get a [note widget application](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note&hl=en). You can then single click the note widget and it will copy to your clipboard to paste into wherever you wish.

Otherwise as you said you'll have to use a 3rd party app to first locate yourself. It's more the webservices fault for not binding with your phone and asking for the location, write them a strongly worded letter :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try **[Zip Code Finder](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.minstech.tool.activity&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5taW5zdGVjaC50b29sLmFjdGl2aXR5Il0)**.